# Another way of stopping text wrapping image than using overflow: hidden

Tags: css, image, media-queries, overflow, word-wrap

I'm using a media query @480, however, cannot get the text to stop wrapping the image. Overflow: hidden/auto works, however this then affects the text/caption within the image i.e. cuts off some of the text.

Could anyone help/advise re: another way of achieving this based on the code below:

**Front end**

```
<div class="outer">
    <figure class="img1 embed news">
        <img src="Images/windscreen.jpg" alt="Windscreen">
        <figcaption>A fifth of people use a bank card to scrape their car's windscreen.</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<p>Many people in the UK rely on bank cards to allow them to take out money from their bank account. However, it seems a large number of people are abusing their card, which means that they risk damaging them, as well as misplacing them.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      max-width: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto; 
    }

    figure.embed,
    figure.embed-top,
    figure.overlay,
    figure.embed-over {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0em;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        background: white;
        width: 100%;
    }

    figure.embed img,
    figure.embed-top img,
    figure.overlay img,
    figure.embed-over img {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    figure.embed figcaption,
    figure.embed-top figcaption,
    figure.overlay figcaption,
    figure.embed-over figcaption {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5em;
        /* neutral theme */
        color: rgba(50,50,50,1.0);
        background: rgba(200,200,200,0.825);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `word-wrap` tag in CSS3. Refer to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)